# use of index with a hash instead of an array

Tags: ruby

I use in a genealogy program following method to add a mariage/spouse to a Person.
@mariages is an array of arrays.

```
def add_spouse(spouse, mariage_date = nil, divorce_date = nil)
  @mariages.push([spouse, mariage_date, divorce_date]) unless @mariages.index{|(a, b, c)| a == spouse && b == mariage_date} 
  spouse.mariages.push(self) unless spouse.mariages.index{|(a, b, c)| a == self && b == mariage_date} 
end
```

With the `unless @mariages.index{|(a, b, c)| a == spouse && b == mariage_date}` i check if the mariage is not allready in the array.

Now i want to keep my mariages in an array of hashes like this

```
def add_spouse(spouse, mariage_date = nil, divorce_date = nil)
    @mariages.push({:spouse => spouse, :mariage_date => mariage_date, :divorce_date => divorce_date}) unless ...
    spouse.mariages.push({:spouse => self, :mariage_date => mariage_date, :divorce_date => divorce_date}) unless ... 
end
```

Can someone help me adapt the unless part to do the check if the hash is not allready presant in the array ?

Comment: This design's [primitive obsession](http://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/primitive-obsession)  is screaming for an object. Why not make a marriage an object and have a collection of marriages. That way you can set up equality and test your collection using some higher-level construct.

Comment: thanks for your advise Paul, could you give an example how to implement add_marriage (or add_spouse) with marriage as an object and how the comparing would be done ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the block that goes into `index` the element getting iterated over is a hash so you should use

```
.. unless @mariages.index{|h| h[:spouse] == spouse && h[:mariage_date] == mariage_date}
```

and

```
.. unless spouse.mariages.index{|h| h[:spouse] == self && h[:mariage_date] == mariage_date}
```

PS: `mariage` is misspelled. It should be marriage.

Answer (score 1):

Since your array now contains hashes instead of other arrays, you can't use "array unpacking" (not sure what's the official term for that is). You will get an instance of hash, and you can access it as you normally would.

```
 @mariages.push({:spouse => spouse, 
                 :mariage_date => mariage_date, 
                 :divorce_date => divorce_date}) unless @mariages.index{|h| h[:spouse] == spouse && h[:mariage_date] == mariage_date}
```

Answer (score 1):

As per your question in the commend I'd do something like the following. Note that Dates should use the date class and the partners in the marriage should be classes too, with births and deaths and whatnot. But hopefully you can see how moving the data into objects that know what to do with it, can simplify the design as things get larger. (I also went with bride and groom for simplicity, feel free to change that in a genealogically approved manner).

Each person would have a Marriages associated with them and if you had a bride and a groom they could share a single Marriage, but have a different list of Marriages.

```
class Marriage
  attr_accessor :marriage_date, :divorce_date, :bride, :groom

  def initialize(date, bride, groom)
    @marriage_date = date
    @bride = bride
    @groom = groom
  end

  def marriage_equals(m)
    return (@marriage_date == m.marriage_date) && 
           (@bride == m.bride) &&
           (@groom == m.groom)
  end    
end

class Marriages
  def initialize
    @marriages = []
  end

  def add_marriage(marriage)
    if (@marriages.any? { |m| m.marriage_equals(marriage) })
      puts "Marriage of #{marriage.groom} already listed"
      return false
    else
      puts "Added new marriage"
      @marriages.push(marriage)
      return true
    end
  end

end


m1 = Marriage.new("1-1-0002", "Wilma", "Fred")
m2 = Marriage.new("6-8-0003", "Betty", "Barney")
m3 = Marriage.new("2-8-8003", "Jane", "George")


marriages = [m1,m2]
p marriages.any? { |m| m.marriage_equals(m1) } # true
p marriages.any? { |m| m.marriage_equals(m3) } # false

m_list = Marriages.new
m_list.add_marriage(m1) # Added new marriage
m_list.add_marriage(m2) # Added new marriage
m_list.add_marriage(m2) # Marriage of Barney already listed
```